# Cancel jQuery UI drop once dropped

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

I am using jQuery draggable and droppable.  Sometimes I want to cancel the drop even though the thing being dragged is 'acceptable' to the target.  I only know whether the drop can proceed once the user has released the mouse button (not whilst actually still dragging, which is how 'accept' seems to work).  Is there any way of 'cancelling' the drop within the drop function, or is there another way around this issue?  Thanks very much.

Comment: `.draggable()` and `.droppable()` are part of jQueryUI

Comment: How do you mean "cancel"? You can't re-enter dragging once the user has released the left mouse button physically (would be weird).

Comment: You can limit where an object can be dragged to by using the parent element or x, y axis.

Comment: Well the droppable accept function actually fires while the user is still dragging.  This means they can change the coordinates of the dragged item after the droppable accept function has returned true.  In certain circumstances I want to cancel the drop, but once the droppable function has returned true I can't see how to cancel the drop when it actually happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.draggable()` elements fire a `.stop()` event when the user has completed the drag.  You can override the default method with a custom method in the draggable instantiation:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable({
   stop: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```